# CakePHP 3.3 Getting two columns from joined tables

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am new to cakePHP and while trying to work my way around tables I encountered a problem with getting specific colmns from two tables. What I would like to achieve is:

```
SELECT categories_1.category_id,categories_2.name FROM categories_1 JOIN categories_2 ON categories_2.category_id = categories_1.category_id
```

I know I could do:

```
$query=$this->Categories1->find('all')->contain(['Categories2'])
```

However this way I am getting whole table categoires_2 as the inner array which makes the structre more complex and adds unecessary columns from second table.

I tried following the documentation, but the code I came up with doesn't really work:

```
 $query=$this->Categories1->find('all')
                            ->select('Categories2.name','Categories1.category_id')
                            ->join([
                                    'table' => 'categories_2',
                                    'alias' => 'Categories2',
                                    'conditions' => array('Categories2.category_id' => 'Categories1.category_id')     
                            ]);
```

I would appreciate help in correcting the code...
Thanks

EDIT:
The cake is generating the following sql code:

```
SELECT Categories2.name AS `Categories2__name` FROM categories_1 Categories1 INNER JOIN categories_2 Categories2 ON Categories2.category_id = :c0
```

Comment: Btw I have the relations set in Models Categories2 -> belongsto and Categories1 ->hasmany

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't really work"? Pls be specific when you describe the error message or unexpected behaviour!

Comment: Right now there is no error, but the result is empty

Comment: How does the generated sql look like?

Comment: Try this: $query=$this->Categories1->find()->select('Categories2.name','Categories1.category_id')->contain(['Categories_2']);

Comment: @rrd: I tried your script however I did get an error: Categories2.name Column not found:

Comment: you have to pass an array to select(): `->select(['Categories2.name','Categories1.category_id'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the fields you want to have returned

```
$query=$this->Categories1->find('all')->contain(
                                 ['Categories2' => [
                                  'fields' => ['field1', 'field2']   
                                     ]
                                 ]
                           )
```